# For how long has a channel been inactive?

Tags: lightning-network, lightning-network-daemon, ln-closing-channels

I would like to close channels for which there is enough evidence that the remote node disappeared and won't come back.
So my idea was to check for how long a channel has been inactive, and if it is > two months to close that channel.

How could I find out for how long a channel has been inactive (in LND)? Finding out which channels are inactive is easy by querying`lncli listchannels --inactive_only`, but the result does not show any indicator about how long that channel has been inactive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look for "last_update" field in `getchaninfo` output.

Below I also submitted https://github.com/edouardparis/lntop console screenshot which does the same thing.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the command you are looking for is

```
admin@myNode:~ $ lncli getchaninfo --chan_id CHANNELIDVALUE
```

Comment: pretty much the same answer that had already been accepted years ago.